# Attempting to derive the solution for this secretary problem variant... (Best or Second Best)

Tags: probability

We have the variant of "Choosing the best or second best secretary" for the secretary problem where you win if you choose either the best or second best on offer. The solution to maximise the probability of doing so goes as follows:

"Pass $s_1 − 1$ draws, then choose the first candidate thereafter, but beginning with the $s_2$th
draw, choose also a drawing that is second best among those so far made.
Naturally $s_1$ and $s_2$ are chosen to maximise P, the probability of winning.
For a given $n$, P breaks into three parts: the probability of winning by choosing the largest so far on
draw $i$, $s_1 ≤ i ≤ s_2$; the probability of winning by choosing the largest so far
on draw i, $s_2 + 1 ≤ i ≤ n$, the algebraic form being altered because of the
possible choice of a draw ranked second largest thus far; and the probability
of winning by choosing the second-largest draw thus far, $s_2 ≤ i ≤ n$."

Then the solution as written in the 1966 paper jumps straight to this with no more explanation:

$$ P = \frac{s_1 -1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=s_1}^{s_2} [\frac{2(n-1)}{i-1} -1] $$
$$+ \frac{(s_1 - 1)(s_2 -2)}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=s_2+1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-2}[\frac{2(n-1)}{i-1}-1]$$
$$+\frac{(s_1-1)(s_2-2)}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=s_2}^{n}\frac{1}{i-2}$$

and then moves to this as a simplification:

$$P = \frac{2(s_1-1)}{n} \sum_{i=s_1}^{s_2}\frac{1}{i-1}$$

$$+ \frac{(s_1-1)(s_1-s_2)}{n(n-1)} + \frac{2(s_1-1)(s_2-2)}{n}[\frac{1}{s_2-1} - \frac{1}{n-1}]$$

From what I have researched, there is no source that derives this solution in detail. I have been attempting to do this myself, for greater understanding. Looking at the 1966 paper, I understand generally where things are supposed to come from but some of these things don't make much intuitive sense to me. I had an attempt at doing my own solution myself in a much more transparent manner and I ended up with this (now updated through edits):

$$ P = \sum_{i=1}^{s_1-1} 0 + \sum_{s_1}^{s_2-1} \frac{s_1-1}{i-1} \cdot \frac{2}{n} + \sum_{i=s_2}^{n} \frac{s_1-1}{i-1} \cdot \frac{s_2-2}{i-2} \cdot \frac{2}{n} + \sum_{i=s_2}^{n} \frac{s_1-1}{i-1} \cdot \frac{s_2-2}{i-2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

The way this works is the first $s_1 - 1$ choices will never be chosen so the probability is 0.

Furthermore, between $s_1$ and $s_2$, it is just like the normal secretary problem where we look for the next best applicant who is better than all the ones previous. This occurs when the best applicant during $i-1$ was within $s_1 - 1$. We also multiply this by $\frac{2}{n}$ as this is the probability that $i$ is best or second best. After this, it gets slightly trickier.

We shall split the sums after $s_2$ into two portions, as described in the original solution's optimal method. One where we go after the best overall, and one where we go after the second best overall. Surely when going after the best overall after $r_2$, this occurs similar to our second sum, i.e. the best from $i-1$ must still be locked within those first $s_1 -1$ applicants? (Edit 3: This is indeed true, but there is another probability we must take into account. See: Edit 2).

---

Edit: okay, I think I've made some head-way. The way that $i$ will be selected after the $s_2$ point as the second best, given that it is second best, is if, and only if, the following TWO things hold:

- for $i$ to be selected, the best of the first $i-1$'s must be in the first $s_1-1$'s $ \implies \frac{s_1-1}{i-1}$ as a probability.
- there must be no applicant within the $[s_2, i-1]$ applicant range that is the second best of the first $i-1$. This effectively is the same as saying that the second best of the $i-1$ applicants came BEFORE the $s_2$ boundary. THUS, we get a probability of $\frac{s_2 - 1}{i-1}$, right?

Now... for these to both be true at the same time... they of course cannot be the same applicant as each other, which is why our second probability changes to $\frac{s_2 - 2}{i-2}$ as they must each occupy a different space. We are getting somewhere now, and it is looking closer to the original 1966 solution.

---

Edit 2: I believe I have made another 'breakthrough'. When picking the best applicant $i$ after the $r_2$ boundary, we must ensure that there is no 'second best' option after the $r_2$ and before $i$, as that would cause this to be chosen instead. This is an extra probability of $\frac{r_2 - 1}{i-1}$. Almost identically to our edit 1 argument, these cannot be the same applicant, so this becomes $\frac{r_2 - 2}{i-2}$. We now arrive incredibly close to the 1966 original solution.

---

Edit 4: I suppose we can rather clearly now see that my derived answer is almost identical to the posted 1966 answer. We are certainly along the right lines. There are only two values left in the OG solution that I am not sure where they appear from.

1. The $-1$ values at the end of lines 1 and 2 of the original solution. Nevertheless, once the summations are simplified, the $-1$ values seem to vanish for some reason. So perhaps they are unimportant for our problem.
2. I have $\frac{1}{i-1}$ on my final summation, whereas the original solution has $\frac{1}{n-1}$. I am unsure why this discrepancy exists.

Comment: Cool problem. I guess the first step is, as in the paper, to divide the sum after $s_2$ in two parts: the one where you win because you choose the best candidate after $s_2$ and the one in which you win because you choose the second best candidate after $s_2$.

Comment: For sure this is what I need to do, but I am unsure how to work out the probabilities that go in front of the two sums at the end. I have given it a go, now, but I know they are wrong.